# Show subcategories instead of actual products in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

In wooCommerce when you click on a category (WC side bar product filter) it displays only the products but the subcategories. How can I change this behavior so that parent and child and other nodes shows not the actual product. I have to set this so the user passes through more subcategory before they see the product.

I know I can build static pages this way but is there way to edit category system somehow?

Just an example:

Men Clothing –> Jeans —-> some brand —-> and then they see all products related to that brands. Right now when i click on Clothing it brings all products from these subcategories which looks like a mess.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: For each category settings you have a **Display type** selector with: "Default", "Products", "subcategories" or "Both"… So I think you need to set this to "Products" for each of them. That's all.

Comment: Thank you that solved it